# Pass sum of total of column show in google charts

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
<script>
   $("input.JKLL").each(function(i) { // select all column total elements
        this.value = columnTotals[i];
        var ChartData = this.value;
    }
    google.charts.load('current', {
        'packages': ['bar']
    }); google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
    function drawChart(ChartData) {
        //var datas = null;
        var chartData = ChartData;
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(chartData)
        var options = {
            bars: 'vertical' // Required for Material Bar Charts.
        };
        var chart = new
        google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data,
            google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));
    });
</script>
<div id="chart_div" style="width: 1150px; height: 300px"></div>
```

I want to show my data in ChartData in a Google chart. I have a 7 value in ChartData and I declare this data in Google chart data, but it's not working.

Comment: can you show , what is drawn and what u want ?

Comment: @manikantgautam i want to  draw only 7 values which is in chartData .And these 7 value is show by bar chart thats it.

Comment: Look at http://jsfiddle.net/rekso9t6/58/

Comment: @manikantgautam But  my data is only in chartData  i do not want  give any manually value.

Comment: you didn't expose statement `var ChartData = this.value;` . So it is unclear what is your data format.

Comment: @manikantgautam my data fromat is 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 values in chartData.And i want to show these 7 values in google chart.